# Process is terminated due to overflow

Tags: c#, .net

Process is terminated due to stackoverflow.

if I use C# accessors to get the printer name, it will cause stackoverflow.

```
Receipt.cs


public String printer_name
        {
            set { this.printer_name = value; }
            get { return this.printer_name; }
        }

Program.cs

   receipt.amount = 101;
   receipt.drawnBy = "haha";
   receipt.printer_name = @"RP80 Printer";
```

If I directly assign the printer name, it will not get this problem.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

Your `printer_name` property is causing an infinite recursion. Use an auto property instead:

```
public String printer_name { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because in your property `printer_name` setter you are calling `this.printer_name = value;`, which calls the same property setter once again and it continues many times.

In order to fix it you need to introduce a variable with a different name, for example:

```
private string _printerName;
public String printer_name
{
    set { this._printerName = value; }
    get { return this._printerName; }
}
```

It is very likely that you are using .NET 2.0 or later, in this case the above code can be simplified to a single line:

```
public String printer_name { get; set; }
```